# Access cell by corresponding column text in HTML table

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get cell text by corresponding cell.

```
Column 1     Column 2
Deadline     02 Jul 2020
```

So by finding "Deadline" I need to get the date.

Here is HTML:

[image]

I am trying to use:

```
var MDeadline = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[./th[text()='Deadline']]/../td[1]"));
```

without success. What would be the right XPath?

**Deadline:**

Full XPath:

```
/html/body/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/th
```

XPath:

```
//*[@id="advsearchformdiv"]/tbody/tr[7]/th
```

**Date:**

Full XPath:

```
/html/body/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td
```

XPath:

```
//*[@id="advsearchformdiv"]/tbody/tr[7]/td
```

Sometimes it is `tr[6]`, sometimes `tr[7]` that's why I need to stick logic to word "Deadline" without using full XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below **xpath** options

Here since you are referring row you just need to `select td tag` under that row.

```
var MDeadline = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[./th[text()='Deadline']]/td"));
```

OR select hearder tag and `following-sibling::td` of that header tag

```
var MDeadline = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//th[text()='Deadline']/following-sibling::td"));
```

Comment: First one worked! Thank you! I have to investigate the logic now